# Tiny MCE Editor Selection Issue in Angular

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor, while selecting a single tag it returns correct value using this function `editor.selection.getNode()`. but when i am selecting two tags data it returns all HTML content from the editor.

Example given below Screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNuOa.png)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the content area of the TinyMCE editor is a full DOM tree with `<head>` and `<body>` elements. (These are usually obscured from the end user unless the [Full Page](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/fullpage/) plugin is used.)

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getnode), `.getNode()` returns:

> ...the currently selected element or the common ancestor element for both start and end of the selection.

With HTML like:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
```

the "common ancestor element" for the selection would be the `<body>` element that wraps all content in the editor.